# PDF of $Z^2$ where $Z$ is uniform $[-1,1]$

Tags: probability, statistics

(a) Let $Z$ be uniform $[-1,1]$. What is the PDF of $Z^2$.

I would like to fix my previous statement. Using the textbook for uniform $[0,1]$ the PDF of $Z^2$
Say $Y=Z^2$.

The CDF
$$P(Z^2\le y) = P(-\sqrt {y} \le Z \le \sqrt{y})= F_Y(\sqrt{y})-F_Y(\sqrt{-y})$$ 
Differentiate to obtain the PDF 
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt y}f_Y(\sqrt y)+\frac{1}{2\sqrt y}f_Y(\sqrt{-y})$$ This is correct if $Z$ ~ $[0,1]$. Does the problem change greatly due to the new interval?

Comment: "I have solved the following problem" You mean, **you** have solved it yourself? Then why do you have any trouble retracing your own steps when Z is uniform on [-1,1] instead of on [0,1]? If ever you would have actually **copied verbatim** this proof from somebody else without understanding anything in it, please know that making us believe the proof is yours is most inappropriate.

Comment: @Did I saw this proof in the textbook a while back, and when I wrote it here, it was strictly from my memory. I guess even the fact that I wrote it due to the textbook is copying. I did not have this intention and have fixed my initial post.

Comment: If $A\sim U(0,1)$ and $B\sim U(-1,1)$ then $A^2$ and $B^2$ have precisely the same distribution by the parity of $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I tried the following approach, but I am not sure whether or not it is correct. I split the interval from (-1,0) and (0,1) but now the height of each becomes 1/2. With the similar approach from above, I solved the the (0,1) with the new height and then multiplied my answer by 2. Is this a correct way of approaching the problem?

Comment: @andreawong: if you take a probability density function and you multiply it by $2$ you do not have a probability density function anymore!

Answer (score -1):

\begin{align}
P(Z^2 \leq y) &= P(-\sqrt{y} \leq Z \leq \sqrt{y}) \\
&= F_Z(\sqrt{y}) - F_Z(-\sqrt{y})
\end{align}

Differentiating

$$f_{Z^2}(y) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}f_Z(\sqrt{y}) + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}f_Z(-\sqrt{y}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}f_Z(\sqrt{y})$$

I will leave the evaluation of $f_Z(\sqrt{y})$ as an exercise.

Comment: Copying parts of the question? What for?